# Isospin multiplet for a given pentaquark

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, isospin-symmetry, pentaquarks

Considering the pentaquark $P = (uudt\bar{c})$, with orbital angular momentum $L = 0$, and assuming a space-spin wavefunction that corresponds to the maximum-J state, I want to know the isospin multiplet to which $P$ belongs.

First of all, the maximum-J state would be $J = \frac{5}{2}^-$, as we are dealing with a pentaquark (a combination of a proton and a meson here).

At this point, for the $J$ above, the maximum isospin $I$ for $P$'s multiplet would be $I = \frac{3}{2}$, since the only particles that account for the isospin are the quarks $u$ and $d$ and their respective antiquarks. Therefore, the asked multiplet would be the following quadruplet:

$$|dddt\bar{c}>$$
$$|uddt\bar{c}>$$
$$|uudt\bar{c}>\;=P$$
$$|uuut\bar{c}>$$

Is this procedure at all correct?

Comment: Looks "theoretically" sensible, but, you know, *t* s decay before they hadronize...

Comment: $\Gamma_t \approx 10 \Lambda_{QCD}$...